# How to look at the memory from one's local variables in Eclipse of a completed run?

Tags: eclipse, notepad++

So I used eclipse to write out a new file, but I accidentally overrode an old file I was using in Notepad++ with a lot of important data on it. In one of my local variables it had the contents of the old file, is it possible to get it back or is it just gone?

I've tried using the windows restore previous versions function but windows doesn't have it and I've looked at the notepad++ backup folder in the %AppData% folder but it's not there either. Any eclipse wizards know a way to examine the variables of a completed run?

Comment: In Eclipse, right-click the file and choose _Replace With > Local History..._. Or did you run code that overrode the old file?

Comment: The latter. I ran code that overrode the old file.